# Retain color and format of Bash command in a variable

Tags: bash

team!
I want to execute bash command into variable.

```bash
COMMAND="systemctl status wazuh-manager --no-pager"
NEWMESSAGE="$($COMMAND)"
if [[ -n $NLINES ]]; then
     $NEWMESSAGE | tail -n $NLINES
fi
if [[ -n $OUTPUTFILE ]]; then
    echo -e $NEWMESSAGE |& tee -a $OUTPUTFILE
fi
```

I have output like this. 
Single line with no color text.

```
● wazuh-manager.service - Wazuh manager Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wazuh-manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-30 19:58:47 MSK; 17h ago Process: 12449 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-control start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) Tasks: 138 (limit: 28719) Memory: 1.0G CGroup: /system.slice/wazuh-manager.service ├─12505 /var/ossec/framework/python/bin/python3 /var/ossec/api/scripts/wazuh-apid.py ├─12526 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-integratord ├─12547 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-authd ├─12563 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-db ├─12577 /var/ossec/framework/python/bin/python3 /var/ossec/api/scripts/wazuh-apid.py ├─12580 /var/ossec/framework/python/bin/python3 /var/ossec/api/scripts/wazuh-apid.py ├─12592 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-execd ├─12606 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-analysisd ├─12621 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-syscheckd ├─12683 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-remoted ├─12715 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-logcollector ├─12735 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-monitord └─12756 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-modulesd May 30 19:58:39 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-analysisd... May 30 19:58:40 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-syscheckd... May 30 19:58:41 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-remoted... May 30 19:58:43 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-logcollector... May 30 19:58:44 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-monitord... May 30 19:58:44 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12753]: 2022/05/30 19:58:44 wazuh-modulesd: WARNING: The <ignore_time> tag at module 'vulnerability-detector' is deprecated for version newer than 4.3. May 30 19:58:44 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12753]: 2022/05/30 19:58:44 wazuh-modulesd: WARNING: Invalid option 'os' for 'msu' provider at 'vulnerability-detector' May 30 19:58:45 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-modulesd... May 30 19:58:47 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Completed. May 30 19:58:47 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local systemd[1]: Started Wazuh manager.
```

but if i run command in console i have different format.

```bash
systemctl status wazuh-manager --no-pager
● wazuh-manager.service - Wazuh manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wazuh-manager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-30 19:58:47 MSK; 18h ago
    Process: 12449 ExecStart=/usr/bin/env /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-control start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 138 (limit: 28719)
     Memory: 1.0G
     CGroup: /system.slice/wazuh-manager.service
             ├─12505 /var/ossec/framework/python/bin/python3 /var/ossec/api/scripts/wazuh-apid.py
             ├─12526 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-integratord
             ├─12547 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-authd
             ├─12563 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-db
             ├─12577 /var/ossec/framework/python/bin/python3 /var/ossec/api/scripts/wazuh-apid.py
             ├─12580 /var/ossec/framework/python/bin/python3 /var/ossec/api/scripts/wazuh-apid.py
             ├─12592 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-execd
             ├─12606 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-analysisd
             ├─12621 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-syscheckd
             ├─12683 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-remoted
             ├─12715 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-logcollector
             ├─12735 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-monitord
             └─12756 /var/ossec/bin/wazuh-modulesd

May 30 19:58:39 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-analysisd...
May 30 19:58:40 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-syscheckd...
May 30 19:58:41 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-remoted...
May 30 19:58:43 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-logcollector...
May 30 19:58:44 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-monitord...
May 30 19:58:44 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12753]: 2022/05/30 19:58:44 wazuh-modulesd: WARNING: The <ignore…n 4.3.
May 30 19:58:44 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12753]: 2022/05/30 19:58:44 wazuh-modulesd: WARNING: Invalid opt…ector'
May 30 19:58:45 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Started wazuh-modulesd...
May 30 19:58:47 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local env[12449]: Completed.
May 30 19:58:47 UBUNTU-2004-SRV-2.home.local systemd[1]: Started Wazuh manager.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

> **How to save text format?**

Comment: Double quote your variables.

Comment: Thanks, but what about colors?

Comment: When not running in a TTY terminal, `systemctl` does not output colours. Also the output in a terminal may differs by using abbreviated unit names unless you specify the `--full` option switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the format and pass the color format of the output of `systemctl status ...`. you can use;

```
$ var="$(SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status wazuh-manager.service)"
$ echo "$var"
```

The color as well as the format wil now be preserved

Comment: This is a duplicate and a bash FAQ topic

Comment: @LéaGris Where is the duplicate? I have looked at the link provided as a dupe and it does not mention how to pass the color to the variables output

Comment: Poster stores command with argument into a variable.

Comment: @LéaGris I think you misunderstood the request as did I until OP mentioned they needed to pass colors which made it different, but sure, if you feel it is a dupe.